# Estimate RBF SVM training time in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, svm, smo

I coded a SMO Algorithm in matlab by myself. I would like to evaluate the time it will take to train.
My dataset is 7000 samples and 1000 features
C = 10, epsilon=0.1, teta(RBF)=0.1

My CPU is i3 3.3GHz and my RAM is 8Go.

I started training there is one day and it is not finished yet.

I already coded a Viola Jones algorithm which takes weeks to learn, I wanted to know if this is the same thing for SVM.

Comment: You most certainly have an infinite loop somewhere. Training on such a small training set should take a few minutes at most to finish.

Comment: I am not sure to have an infinite loop because I tried before with a dataset of 100 samples and 1000 features and it worked (2 minutes to compute)

Comment: That is still abnormally long, though. Your convergence is probably a lot slower than it should be.